# How to get the sum of items inside an `innerText` from a table that was created in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a code that adds rows to a table from items in a database using AJAX. That part works fine but I need to calculate the sum off the the numbers in the rows that I created, but for some reason everything I tried didnt work.

My code :

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/api/001,
      dataType: "json",

      success: function(data) {

        for (var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {

          $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(dateArray[0]),
            $('<td class="duration">').text(dateArray[1]),

          ).appendTo('#testtable');

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="testtable">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
  </tr>
```

This successfully insert the data to the table, but I'm trying to get the sum of `Duration` but can't seem to get it to work. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you create the table you should give each  the "duration" class, then iterate through each element and store the value as an int. then sum up those values.
for example :

```
<table id="testtable">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="duration"><td >5</td><td class="duration">5</td></tr>
</table>

<script>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Loop through each div element with the class box
total =0;
    $(".duration").each(function(){
        stringval = jQuery(this).text();
        num = parseInt(stringval);
total += num;
        ;


    });
    console.log(total);
});'''
</script>
```

This will return 10